# How to know when a Kendo grid row is in Edit mode

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How to know when a Kendo grid row is in Edit mode without using grid edit event?

```
var tanquesGrid = $(".tanques").data("kendoGrid");
tanquesGrid.element.delegate("tbody>tr", "dblclick", function () {
       var selectedItem = tanquesGrid.dataItem(tanquesGrid.select());
       if (hasWriteAccess && isClosed == false && selectedItem.EquipmentHistoricID != '')
             tanquesGrid.editRow($(this));
});
```

The problem is that when row is in inline edit mode and I double click on it, edit mode disappear, this way (code above) I resolve this in new row where the id ! = '' but when edit an existing row the problem persist.

any ideas??

Sorry about my english

Comment: Edit row has class selector class="k-grid-edit-row". Maybe that could help?

Answer (score 7):

```
          if ( $('#grid').find('.k-grid-edit-row').length ) {
            //grid is not in edit mode          
           } else {
                //grid is in edit mode
                grid.editRow($(this));
            }
```

Comment: length will be always zero or greater than zero. so in this case grid will always show as not in edit mode.
we have to change if ( $('#grid').find('.k-grid-edit-row').length ) to 

if ( $('#grid').find('.k-grid-edit-row').length > 0 ) {
            //grid is in edit mode          
           } else {
                //grid is not in edit mode
            }

Answer (score 5):

It's not in the published API but the grid has a property "editable" which will be non-null when in edit mode.

Comment: This works. If avoiding jquery this may be the answer you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
    $('#myGrid').find('.k-grid-edit-row');
```

When the grid is in edit mode, the editing row has a class of "k-grid-edit-row".

This jquery statement will look for a row with the edit mode class within the table of id = "myGrid".

Comment: Please explain your answer. SO exists not just to answer question, but to educate people.